# SQL Server Order first by ParentID, then Child

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently dealing with a database my company is phasing out, and we're trying to build a quick and dirty interface so that people can easily extract some data. A major problem with this database however, is that the primary assets are all recorded in one large table in order of when they were created, not how they relate to one another.

The gist of the database is shown below:

```
ParentAssetID ChildAssetID AssetName
------------------------------------
84            2            abc
35            1            cdf
956           35           PARENT35
84            1            ghi
956           3            PARENT3
35            3            jkl
956           84           PARENT84
3             5            mno
```

I would like to, using a select statement, output this ordered in such a way so that it appears as below:

```
ParentAssetID ChildAssetID AssetName
------------------------------------
956           3            PARENT3
3             5            mno
956           35           PARENT35
35            1            cdf
35            3            jkl
956           84           PARENT84
84            1            ghi
84            2            abc
```

As you can see, the data is first sorted by the ChildAssetID, and then each child of that asset is sorted below it. It's a pain to deal with, and that's one of the reasons why we're trying to get rid of it.

Currently, all I've got is the following:

```
select ParentAssetID, ChildAssetID, AssetName from dbo.Assets order by ParentAssetID
```

however this only groups the child assets all together without their parent headings at the start - they're all the way down the bottom at 956, grouped with *their* parent's children. Is there any way to sort the table like this so it's easily human readable, or will this job have to be done by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this using CTE

```
;with cte as
(
select
    ParentAssetID,
    ChildAssetID,
    AssetName,
    cast(row_number()over(partition by ParentAssetID order by AssetName) as varchar(max)) as [path],
    0 as level,
    row_number()over(partition by ParentAssetID order by AssetName) / power(10.0,0) as x
from Assets
where ParentAssetID =956
union all
select
    t.ParentAssetID,
    t.ChildAssetID,
    t.AssetName,
    [path] +'-'+ cast(row_number()over(partition by t.ParentAssetID order by t.AssetName) as varchar(max)),
    level+1,
    x + row_number()over(partition by t.ParentAssetID order by t.AssetName) / power(10.0,level+1)
from
    cte
join Assets t on cte.ChildAssetID = t.ParentAssetID
)

select
    ParentAssetID,
    ChildAssetID,
    AssetName,
    [path],
    x
from cte
order by x
```

Comment: That worked straightaway! Didn't need to modify a thing! Thankyou so much!

Comment: @Doofitator, I am glad to hear that

Answer (score 2):

For your example this could work:

```
SELECT t1.*
       FROM elbat t1
       ORDER BY CASE
                  WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                          FROM elbat t2
                                          WHERE t2.childassetid = t1.parentassetid) THEN
                    t1.childassetid
                  ELSE
                    t1.parentassetid
                END,
                CASE
                  WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                          FROM elbat t2
                                          WHERE t2.childassetid = t1.parentassetid) THEN
                    0
                  ELSE
                    1
                END,
                t1.childassetid;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9aa938a9224f22e5c787c56d34325e87)

The first `CASE` gets all children and their parent together, the second makes sure the parent is atop and then the children are sorted. If the levels in your real table are any deeper than in the example though, this might no longer work. But maybe you can make something out of it anyways.

Comment: Okay, at the moment that's not working, presumably because the real table is deeper than the example like you said. Currently, that query is very similar to one which sorts the assets by the parentID in ascending order, however there are some minor differences that I'm still trying to understand completely. At any rate, It's quarter past ten and I'm ready for bed - I'll have a look in the morning and report back. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 1):

Your data is a bit awkward, because "mno" has a parent of "3" and "3" is associated with two parent ids.

Other than this, you appear to want to order by the path to the top.  You can do this with a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select a.parentassetid, a.childassetid, a.assetname,
             convert(varchar(max), concat(format(a.parentassetid, '0000'), format(a.childassetid, '0000'))) as path, 1 as lev
      from assets a
      where not exists (select 1 from assets ap where a.parentassetid = ap.childassetid)
      union all
      select a.parentassetid, a.childassetid, a.assetname,
             convert(varchar(max), concat(cte.path, '/', format(a.childassetid, '0000'))), lev + 1
      from cte join
           assets a
           on cte.childassetid = a.parentassetid
      where lev < 10
     )
select *
from cte
order by path;
```

This doesn't produce exactly what you want, because "mno" is duplicated.  I would assume that is a transcription error.

If this is not a transcription error and you want the first time that a row occurs, you can use:

```
select cte.*
from (select cte.*,
             row_number() over (partition by parentassetid, childassetid order by lev asc) as seqnum
      from cte
     ) cte
where seqnum = 1
order by path
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6cf0f7699a94b698060b4418bbd3636d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This looks very promising - and no it wasn't a transcription error, so I do need to include the second block of code. The issue I run across now is that format is not a built in function in my version os SQL Server. If I work it out, I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select
    ParentAssetID,
    ChildAssetID,
    AssetName
from dbo.Assets
order by ParentAssetID desc, ChildAssetID asc;
```

Comment: This sorts everything by ParentAssetID (descending) first, and then by ChildAssetID (ascending) whenever the ParentAssetID fields for two or more rows are equal. This will not give the output as shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Testing answer from @Krishna Muppalla (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59174634/956364)

Is there a way to not use the power(10) functions? I've never seen them used to sort like this!

```
drop table if exists #Assets;

create table #Assets( [ParentAssetID] int, [ChildAssetID] int, [AssetName] varchar(30) );

insert into #Assets( [ParentAssetID], [ChildAssetID], [AssetName] )
select 84,  2,  'abc' union all 
select 35,  1,  'cdf' union all 
select 956, 35, 'PARENT35' union all 
select 84,  1,  'ghi' union all 
select 956, 3,  'PARENT3' union all 
select 35,  3,  'jkl' union all 
select 956, 84, 'PARENT84' union all 
select 3,   5,  'mno';

declare @one float = 1; --I don't know if power(10.0,0) was being recomputed each call.

with [cte] as (
        select
            [ParentAssetID],
            [ChildAssetID],
            [AssetName],
            0 [level],
            row_number() over( partition by [ParentAssetID] order by [AssetName] ) / @one [x]
        from #Assets
        where [ParentAssetID] = 956 --this is bad. How do we get around this?
    union all
        select
            t.[ParentAssetID],
            t.[ChildAssetID],
            t.[AssetName],
            [level] + 1,
            [x] + row_number() over( partition by t.[ParentAssetID] order by t.[AssetName] ) / power(10.0, [level] + 1) [x]
        from [cte]
        join #Assets t on cte.[ChildAssetID] = t.[ParentAssetID]
)
select
    [ParentAssetID],
    [ChildAssetID],
    [AssetName]
    ,[x]
from [cte]
order by [x];
```